# Re-run script after load new content of images into div

Tags: jquery

I've got script for resizing images according to the size of the screen.

Script for images:

```
$(document).ready(function($){

        var ratios,
    adjustSize = function(){

    var total = 520, 
        win = $(window),
        winW = win.width(),
        winH = win.height()-150;

    $('#container img').each(function(i){
        var w = winH * ratios[i];
        $(this).css({
            height: winH,
            width : w   
        });
    total += w;
    });
    $('body').width(total);
};

    $(window).load(function(){
        ratios = $('#container img').map(function(){
            return $(this).width()/$(this).height();
        });
        adjustSize();   
    })
    .resize(function(){ adjustSize(); });
});
```

Everything works great except when I try load new content into div from external file, this script for resizing doesn't re-run again and resize the pictures.

Script for change the content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $("#id").click(function(){
            $('#container').load('some.html').hide().fadeIn('slow');
            });
         });
```

How can I change script?
I tried an event .click() but it doesn't work or maybe I'm doing something wrong.
I'm realy stuck, can anybody help please!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Call adjustSize() function inside load callback instead (before hiding it)

```
$('#container').load('some.html',function(){
     adjustSize();
     $(this).hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: I made a test page, with a help of the second answer, if you want to look at. I's still doesn't work fine, but I'm litle closer. [Test page](http://natasamedvesek.com/test/)

Comment: Here is [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KaWsE/), but it doesn't show external content on click. The problem is that the script doesn't change width of the content immediately, but it does the second time when it is clicked. And also when I click on the link, new content doesn't start scrolling from the begining, but on point where the previous contents ended. –

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access "adjustResize()" function outside its context.

Try adding this to the very top of your file

```
var adjustSize;
```

and then add ";" instead of "," in "ratios," so it will look like this:

```
var ratios;
adjustSize = function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback for `load` to call a function when it's complete:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       // Click event is needed assuming that you want the load to happen only when the element with id 'id' is clicked
       $("#id").on('click', function(){
            $('#container').load('some.html', function () {
                // Do something after load (wrap your image resizing code in a function and call it here)
            })
            .hide().fadeIn('slow');
        });
     });
```

Comment: I've add those lines in script and it's almost perfect. I made a test page. 

[test page](http://natasamedvesek.com/test/)



Can you please look at it. The script doesn't change width of the content immediately, but it does the second time when it is clicked. And also when I click on the link, new content doesn't start scrolling from the begining, but on point where the previous contents ended.